# Can I use <body> as the main grid container in CSS Grid?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Instead of wrapping everything in a `<div>`, can I just the set the `display` of `<body>` to `grid`?

```
<style>
    .grid-container {
        display: grid;
        // Other grid stuff
    }
</style>
…
<body>
    <div class="grid-container">
        <div class="header"></div>
        <div class="other"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

vs.

```
<style>
    body {
        display: grid;
        // Other grid stuff
    }
</style>
…
<body>
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="other"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Have you tried it to see if it works?

Comment: Yes, I've tried it and it works. I'm new to web design and was wondering if that would be proper.

Comment: Yes, it's proper. If the spec doesn't give any cautionary statements or commentary about it not being used for something, then it's usually OK to assume it's fine.